# Is there a function to initialize project on Android Studio 4?

Tags: android-studio

Wondered if a project can be initialized.

I have a completed Android app and have reviewed codes later, would like to modify from it's structure so that looking for a command that return to default project on Android Studio.

Comment: Can you clarify what is exactly you're trying to do? File-New-Project should work to get a default project in most IDEs, but "modify from it's structure" imply you're trying to do something else

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to initialize project and wondered if Android Studio has a faction to do that. If they don't that fine. I rather not using File-New-Project due to a new project won't be able to upload on the exited project on Play Console.

Comment: Play Store require updating an existing app to use the same signing key as the original version. Using File-New Project should work (it can even be an entirely different app developed from Xamarin or React) as long as you still have the private key for signing the app.

Comment: Thank you for providing practical information.